# How can I start services on a remote machine

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I need to know how to start services on a remote computer (I have the username and password). But whenever I try to use ANY remote commands, it always outputs this: "system error 5 has occurred, access is denied." I am running on an admin account with an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Your username on the local machine must have administrator privileges on the remote computer.

Comment: even when I try "net use" in an elevated command prompt, I still get the error.

Comment: Are these computers joined to the same domain or are they just "standalone"?

Comment: they are on the same LAN

Comment: It is not about whether your command prompt has admin rights or not. Does your command prompt is recognised as admin on the other machine. You need to authenticate to the other machine by running something like net use against the other machine. Once your command prompt is authenticated on the other machine then you can run remote commands. Again you need to know the other PC admin username and password.

Comment: @Darius I do know the user/pass but whenever I run "NET USE \\(computer) (password) /user:(username)" it throws the same error